# writing/reading a linked list to binary file

Tags: c, linked-list, binaryfiles

I'm trying to save a linked list to a binary file in C. I think it saves well but when i go to read it, i have a problem ....

Struct

```
typedef struct data plays, *pplays;
struct data{
    int n_play;     // PLAY NUMBER
    int id_player;  // ID OF THE PLAYER
    int piece;      // WHAT PIECE THEY PUT DOWN
    int line;       // WHAT LINE ^
    int column;     // WHAT COLUMN ^^
    pplays next;    // NEXT 
};
```

Save into file

```
void guarda_dados(pplays log, int total){

    FILE *f;
    int i;
    int aux = 0;
    f = fopen("jogo3.bin","wb");
 
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error acessing file.\n");
        return;
    }
    fwrite(&total, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    do{
        fwrite(&log->n_play, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fwrite(&log->line, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fwrite(&log->column, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fwrite(&log->piece, sizeof(int),1, f);
        log = log->next;
        aux++;
    }while(log != NULL);
    fclose(f);


}
```

Read File

```
pplays ler_ficheiro(int *total){
    FILE *f;
    pplays log = NULL;
    pplays aux,new_log;
    *total = 0;
    int i;

    f = fopen("jogo3.bin", "rb");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro no acesso ao ficheiro\n");
        return ;
    }

    fread(total, sizeof(int), 1, f);

    log = malloc(sizeof(plays) * (*total));
    if(log == NULL){
        fclose(f);
        return log;
    }
    printf("total = %d", *total); //TO CHECK IF IT READS THE NUMBER OF STRUCTS INSIDE FILE

        fread(&log->n_play, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->line, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->column, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->piece, sizeof(int),1, f);
        log->next = NULL;


        log = log->next;

        fread(&log->n_play, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->line, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->column, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->piece, sizeof(int),1, f);
        
        log = log->next;

        fread(&log->n_play, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->line, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->column, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&log->piece, sizeof(int),1, f);

    fclose(f);

    return log;
}
```

Main function

```
void main(){

    pplays log = NULL;
    int total = 0;
    int i;
    pplays new_log,aux;




        for(i = 1; i < 4; i++){
            new_log = add_dados(i,i,i,i,i);
            if(log == NULL){
                log = new_log;
            }else {
                aux = log;
                while(aux->next != NULL){
                    aux = aux->next;
                }
                aux->next = new_log;
            }
        }
        i--;


         
            guarda_dados(log, i);
          

            log = ler_ficheiro(&i);

            printf("total 3 = %d \n\n\n ",i);
            show_log(log, i);

            

}
```

This is what I have after reading some explanations here but still cant manage to get it to work properly.

First, I save it into the file with function guarda_dados and then read it from file (everything appears fine).

When I comment the whole code in main function except for the read file, I get an error reading the second log.

EDIT: Read File

```
pplays ler_ficheiro(int *total){
    FILE *f;
    pplays log = NULL;
    pplays aux,new_log;
    *total = 0;
    int i;


    printf("ENTROU AQUI NO LER_FICHEIRO \n\n\n");
    f = fopen("jogo3.bin", "rb");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro no acesso ao ficheiro\n");
        return ;
    }

    fread(total, sizeof(int), 1, f);


    for(i = 0; i < *total;i++){
    printf("ENTROU AQUI %d vezes",i);
        aux = malloc(sizeof(plays));
        if(aux == NULL){
            fclose(f);
            return log;
        }

        fread(&aux->n_play, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&aux->line, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&aux->column, sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&aux->piece, sizeof(int),1, f);

        
        log = aux;
        log = log->next;
       

    }

    show_log(log,*total);

    fclose(f);

    return log;
}
```

Comment: `log->next = NULL; log = log->next;` What do you think the value of `log` is after that? Suggest you run your program in a debugger and step through it.

Comment: so i would have to malloc more memory, is that it ?

Comment: What you need to do is to correctly link each node up. You need to keep a pointer to the previous node so that you can link the current node to it.  And of course you need to use a loop. Listing out the same code over and over again is just not going to work because you don't know how many nodes there are (and it's always horrible to repeat large blocks of code). That's why you have a `total` value in the file - so you can work out how many iterations the loop needs.

Comment: @kaylum i changed it to a loop and still doesnt work. I put the new code in the post in the bottom

Comment: `while(log->next != NULL){ log = log->next;} log = aux;` is a rather inefficient way to get to the tail of the list (you had the tail in the previous iteration of the loop; just keep track of it), but neither `aux->next` nor `log->next` was ever set, so it's not going to work.  You need to set the `next` pointers.

Comment: `Error acessing file.` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Please use: `const char *path = "jogo3.bin"; if( (f = fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL ){ perror(path); ... }`

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, i changed the code and it did work but when i print the struct it doesnt work . So im assuming the reading from file isnt going correctly cause the other function always worked

Comment: It's difficult to follow the code edits. You currently have `aux = malloc(sizeof(plays)); ...  log = aux; log = log->next;`, and that is not valid.  After the `malloc`, `aux->next` is uninitialized.  Reading from it is undefined behavior, so `log = log->next` is undefined behavior.  Perhaps you want to use `calloc`, but more likely you want `prev->next = log = aux; log->next = NULL`, where you've kept track of `prev` from the previous iteration.

Comment: I find you should repost your question, after a number of edits it becomes almost impossible to follow and it is not fair to people answer your question if the question keeps getting changed.

Comment: @kaylum  i managed to change the code and make it work. Thank you kaylum and William

Answer (score 2):

In this line you set log->next to NULL:

```
 log->next = NULL;
```

and immediately after you set log to log->next, making log point to NULL

```
 log = log->next;
```

causing problems for any reference with `log->` after that.

What you need is to make log->next point to an actual memory location, for example with `log->next = malloc(sizeof struct data);` except when there is no next entry where you should set it to NULL.

Comment: i changed the code but it still isnt working. i put the new code in the bottom of the post

Comment: When the `ler_ficheiro()` function returns, `log` points to the `next` value of the last allocated structure, and this `next` value wasn't even assigned a value! So the function returns an invalid pointer. You need to return a pointer to the first allocated structure. The most logical way to approach this is to use a pointer to the pointer that will contain the next allocated structure. I would really recommend you debug your own code step by step so you can learn what happens and what you are doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone and their suggestions. I made the code work thanks to you and after a major change in the code, this is what I got.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "Ficheiros.h"

typedef struct data plays;
struct data{
    int n_play;     // PLAY NUMBER
    int id_player; // ID OF THE PLAYER
    int piece;      // WHAT PIECE THEY PUT DOWN
    int line;       // WHAT LINE ^
    int column;     // WHAT COLUMN ^^
};
void escreve_info(plays a)
{
    printf("Nome: %d\nNº Jogada: %d\tPiece: %d\n", a.id_player, a.n_play, a.piece);
}
plays obtem_info(int id, int play, int piece, int lin, int col){

    plays t;

    t.id_player = id;
    t.n_play = play;
    t.piece = piece;
    t.line = lin;
    t.column = col;

    return t;
}

void escreve_todos(plays log[], int n){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
        escreve_info(log[i]);

}

plays* adiciona_cliente(plays *log, int* n){

    plays *aux;

    aux = realloc(log, sizeof(plays) * (*n + 1));

    if(aux != NULL){
        log = aux;
        log[*n] = obtem_info(*n,*n,*n,*n,*n);
        (*n)++;
    }

    return log;

}

void guardaDadosDin(plays *b, int total){
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    f = fopen("logsD.bin", "wb");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro no acesso ao ficheiro\n");
        return;
    }
    fwrite(&total, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(b, sizeof(plays), total, f);
    fclose(f);
}

plays* leDadosDIN(int *total){
    FILE *f;
    plays *b = NULL;
    *total = 0;
    f = fopen("logsD.bin", "rb");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Erro no acesso ao ficheiro\n");
        return b;
    }
    fread(total, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    b = malloc(sizeof(plays) * (*total));
    if(b == NULL){
        fclose(f);
        return b;
    }
    fread(b, sizeof(plays), *total, f);
    fclose(f);
    return b;
}



void main(){

    plays *log = NULL;
    int total = 0;

    log = adiciona_cliente(log, &total);
    log = adiciona_cliente(log, &total);
    printf("CHEGOU AQUI ?!");
    escreve_todos(log, total);
    guardaDadosDin(log, total);*/
    log = leDadosDIN(&total);

    escreve_todos(log, total);

    if(log != NULL)
        free(log);

    printf("\n\n\n\n Acabou %d\n\n",total);
}
```

It is Writing into binary file, Reading from Binary file and saving it into Struct. Hope it can help somebody else!